# C# regex for matching sepcific text inside nested parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, nested, parentheses

I have these code lines for take to operators between parentheses:

```
string filtered = Regex.Replace(input, "\\(.*?\\)", string.Empty);
var result = filtered.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Where(element => element == "OR" || element == "AND");    
string temp = string.Join(" ", result);
```

These lines do not work for nested parentheses.

For example; it is working for this **input** :

```
X1 OR ( X2 AND X3 AND X4 AND X5 ) OR X6
```

It give me this result: **OR OR**

But, when my input has more than one nested parentheses, it works wrongly.

For this input:

```
X1 OR ( X2 AND( X3 AND X4 ) AND X5 ) OR X6
```

I want to take for result **OR OR** but it prints **OR AND OR**.

Although there are two `(` characters in string, when it ends processing after matching the first `)` character.

How can I adjust my regex pattern?

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions for hierarchies (code; XML et al)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596502/regex-nested-parentheses.

Comment: The one used to close this question is not a complete duplicate, although it does explain the concept and provides an almost exact solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `\(.*?\)` regex contains 3 parts: 1) `\(` matching a literal `(`, 2) `.*?` *lazy* dot matching pattern (that matches 0+ any characters other than a newline, as few as possible, up to the *first* `)`, and 3) a `\)` matching a literal `)`.

Use [**balancing construct**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) **if your strings cannot have escaped sequences**:

```
@"\((?>[^()]|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*\)(?(o)(?!))"
```

The point here is that the expression should not be enclosed with any anchors (as in [*What are regular expression Balancing Groups*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups)).

**Details**:

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `(?>` - start of an atomic group to prevent backtracking into it

  - `[^()]` - any char other than `(` and `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<o>)\(` - matches a literal `(` and pushes an empty value into stack "o"
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<-o>)\)` - matches a literal `)` and removes one value from stack "o"
- `)*` - zero or more occurrences of the atomic group are matched
- `\)`  -  a literal `)`
- `(?(o)(?!))` - a conditional construct failing the match if stack "o" contains values (is not empty).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C((%3F%3E%5B%5E()%5D%7C(%3F%3Co%3E)%5C(%7C(%3F%3C-o%3E)%5C))*%5C)(%3F(o)(%3F!))&i=X1%20OR%20(%20X2%20AND%20X3%20AND%20X4%20AND%20X5%20)%20OR%20X6%0D%0AX1%20OR%20(%20X2%20AND(%20X3%20AND%20X4%20)%20AND%20X5%20)%20OR%20X6).

```
var input = "X1 OR ( X2 AND( X3 AND X4 ) AND X5 ) OR X6";
var filtered = Regex.Replace(input, @"\((?>[^()]|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*\)(?(o)(?!))", string.Empty);
var result = filtered.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(element => element == "OR" || element == "AND");    
var temp = string.Join(" ", result);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/YIKwxE)

Comment: If you'd rather delete the question, please let me know, I will delete my answer.

Comment: I want to remain for this question. Because, i am beginner for c# and i could not solve this problem although to research in this topic. Your answer can assist to other people like me. Thanks again..

Comment: I am sorry for accept process. I do not know enough this platform. I hope it succesful now

Comment: Yes, it is good now. I also added  a human readable description of the pattern.

Comment: I saw it. Thanks for helps.