# C# Regex Select predefined keywords with bracket

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text which is

```
SMA(20, V1) > 200000 AND C1 < LowerBollingerBand(20, 2)
```

after applying regex I need a result like this

```
SMA(20, V1) LowerBollingerBand(20, 2)
```

I can select SMA and LowerBollingerBand by defining these keywords explicitly like this

```
(SMA|LowerBollingerBand)(\()
```

But I am unable to select whatever comes between brackets followed by brackets

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Can the parentheses be nested? Are you looking for just `(SMA|LowerBollingerBand)\([^()]*\)`?

Comment: not now but may be if any string becomes complex then there will nested parentheses

Comment: (SMA|LowerBollingerBand)\([^()]*\) its exactly what I wanted for now

Comment: My Big Thanks to you

Comment: Did I muss anything or will `(.*) > \d{6} AND C1 < (.*)` suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your strings cannot have nested balanced parentheses, you may use  a `[^()]` negated character class to match any symbol but `(` and `)` after `\(` and add a `\)` after to match the close parentheses:

```
(SMA|LowerBollingerBand)\([^()]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(SMA%7CLowerBollingerBand)%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*%5C)&i=SMA(20%2C%20V1)%20%3E%20200000%20AND%20C1%20%3C%20LowerBollingerBand(20%2C%202))

**Details**:

- `(SMA|LowerBollingerBand)` - either `SMA` or `LowerBollingerBand`
- `\(` - a `(`
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)`.

In case there are balanced nested parentheses, use

```
(SMA|LowerBollingerBand)\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(SMA%7CLowerBollingerBand)%5C((%3F%3E%5B%5E()%5D%2B%7C(%3F%3Cc%3E)%5C(%7C(%3F%3C-c%3E)%5C))*(%3F(c)(%3F!))%5C)&i=SMA(20%2C%20SMA(V1))%20%3E%20200000%20AND%20C1%20%3C%20LowerBollingerBand(20%2C%202))

The `\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)` construct matches balanced nested parentheses, see [this answer for a description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19597456/3832970). More on this can be found at the [regular-expressions.info *Balancing Groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html).

Comment: Done. Thanks again