# how to keep space at the start and/or end of a string using split

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently trying to split a string into its pieces using this:

```
var output = Regex
                .Split(input, @"(?<=[)])\s*|\s*(?=[(])")
                .Where(s => s != string.Empty)
                .ToList();
```

The input string is: `"hmmmmmmmm (red,asdfhqwe) asasd"`

The wanted output is: `"hmmmmmmmm "`, `"(red,asdfhqwe)"`, `" asasd"`.

the output I'm getting is: `"hmmmmmmmm"`, `"(red,asdfhqwe)"` and `"asasd"`.

How can i include the spaces when splitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current `(?<=[)])\s*|\s*(?=[(])` regex [matches 0+ whitespaces with `\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/eDqirj/1), and that is why they are missing.

You might just remove `\s*` from the regex, and `(?<=[)])|(?=[(])` should already work in most cases.

However, you may use other approaches where you can control what `(...)` substrings you split out.

For example, you may use `(\([^()]*\))` regex:

```
var output = Regex
            .Split(input, @"(\([^()]*\))")
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            .ToList();
```

It will match and capture substrings inside parentheses and thus the matches will also be part of the resulting list.

See the [online C# demo](http://rextester.com/DDDBN24341) and the [online regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29&i=hmmmmmmmm+%28red%2casdfhqwe%29+asasd).

Split list:

[image]

**NOTE**: To split out substrings between balanced parentheses, use

```
@"(\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*\)(?(c)(?!)))"
```

See [another C# demo](http://rextester.com/CER39201). See [this answer for this regex description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19597456/3832970). More on this can be found at the [regular-expressions.info *Balancing Groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html).

Comment: Yes, I added a rextester fiddle link, IDEONE is crashing all the time.