# RegEx that would change only top level function declarations

Tags: c#, regex

I have Javascript files containing functions of the form:

```
function xyz(a,b,c,...){
....
}
```

I want to change them to the following form for the sake of Typescript migration:

```
private xyz(a,b,c,...){
....
}
```

I could use "`function(.*)\(.*\)`" but if there are nested functions, I need to leave them unchanged.

What would be the proper C# RegEx for this?

Comment: I assume you've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns already... if not - good stating point...  Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596502/regex-nested-parentheses can even be used as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Match:
`function (.+{.*(.*{(?2)}.*)*.*?})` with the multiline parameter on

Then replace with:
`private \1`

This RegEx matches the function entirely, including any nested functions/if statements etc, so you can replace only the outermost one.

Explanation

```
function                Matches function keyword
         (              Starts capture group
          .+            Matches function name and parameters
            {           Opens function
             .*         Matches any code in function
               (        Starts new capture group (2) for catching internal curly braces
                .*      Matches any code in function
                  {     Matches opening curly brace
                   (?2) Matches capture group (2), to match any code and curly braces inside
                  }     Matches closing curly brace
                .*      Matches any code
              )*        Closes capture group (2) and allows it to be repeated
           .*?          Matches any code, until next curly brace
          }             Matches closing curly brace
         )              Closes capture group
```

Note that the recursion (`(?2)`) is not supported in .net by default, so you'll have to use another RegEx-Engine for C#, such as [PCRE for .Net](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net).

If you don't want to use another engine, you can replace the `(?2)` with `(.*{(?2)}.*)*` recursively as deep as you want, as to match nested if loops etc., and finally replace the `(?2)` with `.*`.
The result should look something like this: 
`function (.+{.*(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*)}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*.*?})`

Comment: Could you please provide the expression that I can try on http://regexstorm.net/tester?

Comment: I'm quite sure you are missing both types of strings that can be used inside TypeScript/JavaScript code - `'}'` and `"}"` in your regex similar to the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857054/477420... Also this one have some chance to built complete parser :)

Comment: I tried function (.+{.*(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*)}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*.*}) but it takes the following functions too, until the last "}" character it sees.

Comment: Didn't think about that. Try this: function (.+{.*(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*{(.*)}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*}.*)*.*?})

Answer (score -1):

It may be as simple as matching:

```
/^function/gm
```

Provided your top-level functions have no indentation ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ft1a0M/1)). Or if they are indented to, say, one tab or 4 spaces you could use:

```
/^\tfunction/gm    or    /^    function/gm
```

This uses the start of line anchor (`^`).

Comment: I did not downvote you, but some people will downvote answers to bad questions which are either duplicates or no effort is shown.

Comment: @Wai I'm sure that isn't the case, since the question itself has no downvotes.

Comment: not sure then. It can't be tactical voting because the only answer without downvotes is by a user who cannot currently vote at all.

Answer (score -2):

This would work for you

```
 var src = @"function xyz(a,b,c,...){
   function abc(){
   }
 }";  
 var pattern = @"\s*function\s*(?=\w+\(\w+|,\)\s*\{.+?})";

var result = Regex.Replace(src, pattern, "private ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
result.Dump();
```

---

Check [This](http://regexr.com/490nd)

PS: you need to enable **MultiLine** option

Comment: Tried it with http://regexstorm.net/tester and it could not find a match.

Comment: Check my answer again please

Comment: Does this deal with nested functions as OP alluded to?

Comment: I didn't see that, but now it does. Can you please check it again?

Comment: I just dont get it. the script just works perfectly well. why did I get downvote?

Comment: I am NOT one of the downvoters but here is an example input that does not work: function svdsv() {
        var gsrsgrsgss = this.vdvsdv("sgrgsgrs-sgrsgr");
        this.ssgrgsrsgs();
        this.sgrsgrgsrgs();
        var srgrsgrsg = { srgrsg: srgrsg };
        sgrsg.sgrgs(this, sgrsg.srgrgs + "gr/rs/sr/sr", srg, sgr, srg);
}

Comment: @JohnL. - that's too much :) you only need to have quoted curly inside outer function `function outer(a) { var x="}"; function inner(b) {...}}` check [this](https://regexr.com/490p9) ). Parsing nested constructs with regular expressions is hard even when you use extended regex (as you can't do that with classical Computer Science regular expressions)