# Regex for matching arrays of values or another arrays

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to create a regex which will capture whole array of any objects inside it.

I've got example input string:

```
[2020-05-29T10:00:00, 12.5, 'Test text'][][[], ['Some Data']][['String with[ \'escaped quote][ and parenthesis inside it']]
```

Expected matches are:

```
Match 1: [2020-05-29T10:00:00, 12.5, 'Test text']
Match 2: []
Match 3: [[], ['Some Data']]
Match 4: [['String with[ \'escaped quote][ and parenthesis inside it']] // If this one is possible it's brilliant
```

Regex which I've already created is: `\[[a-zA-Z0-9\-,' :\.\[]*\]`, but it doesn't handle array of arrays and parenthesis inside strings.

I would be really grateful for you help!

Comment: There can be no `[[], []]` match here.

Comment: If you use PCRE, something that could work is `\[\s*(?>((?:'[^\\']*(?:\\[\s\S][^\\']*)*'|[^]'\s,])+)(?:\s*,\s*\g<1>)*|(?R))*\s*]`, but it might not work in all cases. `\[\s*(?>(\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:\[\w+])*|(?:'[^\\']*(?:\\[\s\S][^\\']*)*'|[^]\w])+)(?:\s*,\s*\g<1>)*|(?R))*\s*]` might... But this is all too fragile, you need to get the appropriate parser.

Comment: I have something that will match your 4 matches, but I really need to know the engine before I can post it. It would be helpful if you could add a language tag, as the regex tag asks "this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool".

Comment: @Scratte Added a platform, it's .net C#

Comment: You cannot parse these with a regex, for the reasons explained in detail (for the equivalent problem of parsing HTML with regex) in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: Thank you for updating with the tags. My expression was relying on recursion, which doesn't seem to be supported by .NET. If you decide to switch engine, [you can try it](https://regex101.com/r/onXoqC/1) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the question [Regex nested parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596502/regex-nested-parentheses) - you should look at the accepted answer for a great explanation of what's going on.

The regex you want is, I believe:

```
\[(?>'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|\[(?<DEPTH>)|\](?<-DEPTH>)|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|[^\[\]]+)*\](?(DEPTH)(?!))
```

Comment: Why did you decide it is a .NET related question? Also, it won't work for the case where `[` and `]` are not paired inside a `'...'` string literal. Just checking for the order and amount of open/close brackets in the DEPTH group stack is not a solution here.

Comment: Fair point on the issue with `[` and `]` inside a string Wiktor.  I tested against the provided example (which does work).  .Net - it's what I'm familiar with.  The question doesn't express a specific platform - should have cast my net wider!  I'll update the "answer" to point out the very fair issues you've raised. :-)

Comment: @Brett Sorry for missing a platform in tags. It is exactly .net (C#). This regex is almost perfect, it matches it very well, but this mismatches: `[['String with[ ][ parenthesis inside it']]` First parenthesis is ignored in this case. Almost there

Comment: I think then that we need to consume anything within single quotes (a string) before considering the `[` and `]` for the DEPTH.  I have tested the following which appears to work, assuming that a single quote within a string is escaped by being repeated (e.g. `'a string''s length'`).  Here you go: `\[(?>'.*?'|\[(?<DEPTH>)|\](?<-DEPTH>)|'.*?'|[^\[\]]+)*\](?(DEPTH)(?!))`

Comment: @Brett Brilliant. I've tried to make it work by escaping `'` inside string by using `\'`, it's more .net natural. Is it possible to include this last one adjustment?

Comment: @Brett If this helps there is a regex which respects quotes escaped with `\'` inside strings: `'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'`

Comment: @Brett I think I did it, I've modified your regex to respect escaped quotes inside strings and it looks this way: `\[(?>'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|\[(?<DEPTH>)|\](?<-DEPTH>)|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|[^\[\]]+)*\](?(DEPTH)(?!))`, just please edit your answer with this regex and I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: I've similarly come up with `\[(?>'(\\'|.)*?'|\[(?<DEPTH>)|\](?<-DEPTH>)|'.*?'|[^\[\]]+)*\](?(DEPTH)(?!))`, but happy to put yours in place.